# How to save email address to user phone's address book from my website

Tags: html, mobile

I am working on a mobile website, and I want to add an "Add us to your address book" to the website. When user clicks on the button, our email address will be saved in user phone's address book. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: no access to contact from web app afaik, but you can direct dial from a link

Comment: No.  There is no standard way to do this.  You've got to imagine, there are a lot of different types of phones out there.  There is Android, iOS, Windows Mobile, Blackberry, etc., etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to send vCard file with correct mime type. If supported by handset, phone would save it to contact.